Target class [MyPlaceController] does not exist in Laravel 11
What I did before error:
1. I created a new controller in Controllers with name MyPlaceController

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyPlaceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return 'this is my place';
    }
}

2.
After step 1 i went to web.php and writed a code:

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/my_page', 'MyPlaceController@index');

3. Starting website with command php artisan serve
After this step I got an error with text Target class [MyPlaceController] does not exist.
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [MyPlaceController] does not exist.
4. I tried to create those files by myself, but it didn't worked (I also tried to create those files using cmd, but after creating there was no line with name protected $namespace 'App\\Http\\Controllers)
In the Laravel video course, the author used version 10. To solve this problem he went to the file called RouteServiceProvider.php and uncommented the line with the text: protected $namespace 'App\\Http\\Controllers' and after this action the site worked again, but in my 11 version these files are not present, and therefore I can not do the same as he did. I will also write that I have only a file named AppServiceProvider.php from all 5 files in Providers (but the author has 5 files like in the picture).
Author's files:

AppServiceProvider.php
AuthServiceProvider.php
BroadcastServiceProvider.php
EventServiceProvider.php
RouteServiceProvider.php

And also I want to show my project structure:
My project structure
(just in case, I apologize that my question may not have been posed very correctly)

" but in my 11 version these files are not present" This kind of stuff should now be provided differently in bootstrap/app.php.

Better use [MyPlaceController::class, 'index'] syntax instead of 'MyPlaceController@index' and import that class in your web.php (so it has use App\Http\Controllers\MyPlaceController; kind of line) -- see an example here: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/controllers#basic-controllers

use App\Http\Controllers\MyPlaceController;
    
Route::get('/my_page', [MyPlaceController::class,'index']);

This is the right syntax to define routes in Laravel 11. This is the  default directory structure in Laravel 11.

Thank you so much. Problem was fixed using your answer! :)

so Laravel 11 requires us to explicitly add the use namespace, instead of the autoloader in prior versions?
